# Subclass of NSObject as target in addEventListener statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, addeventlistener

When setting the method of a button call or adding an event listener in objective-c, one normally sets the target to self. However I have a subclass of `NSObject` named `CALLS`, separate from the main file. This subclass has a `void` called `METHOD_NAME` which should be executed.

THe first question is would the void be
+(void)METHOD_NAME

or

-(void)METHOD_NAME
in the subclass.

The next is how would I set the target of the `addEventListener` to use the subclass of `NSObject` and call the method within it. Would I do

target:[CALLS class];

or create an instance of the subclass of NSObject(calls) and then pass that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "CALLS" and "METHOD_NAME" are not good names for a class and method. Try to follow the Objective-C conventions. Since you are "nonono", you might call your class something like `NNEventListener` and the method `buttonTapped`, for example.
- First question: it actually doesn't matter. Class methods (+) and instance methods can both be used. *However*, it would be very unusual to *not* use an instance method for listening to UI events, so the answer is, use `-(void)buttonTapped`
- Second question: I don't think there is a method in all of Cocoa called `addEventListener`. Where did you hear about that? Have you been using web frameworks to make apps before?

To add a **target** to a button (or any other `UIControl`), you use `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` To get a reference to the method that you want to be called, you use the special `@selector` directive like this:

```
[aButton addTarget:anObject action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

`aButton` -- your button
`anObject` -- any object. `self` is just the object that the method belongs to. You can pass in any object at all
`buttonTapped` -- the name of the method that should be called when the button is tapped

Comment: yeah, they were just for example, I'm not really using those names.

Comment: the addEventListener is part of a library